# Python, объясните смысл *args и **kwargs

Tags: python, функции, list, словари

Какой смысл этих параметров, если первый по сути передает list, второй dict? в чем преимущество использования *args и **kwargs?

Пример, где передача *args и list имеют один и тот же смысл и размер кода

**arg**

```
def test_arg(student, *scores):
       print(f"Student Name: {student}")
       for score in scores:
          print(score)

test_arg("Jonathan",100, 95, 88, 92, 99)
```

**list**

```
def test_list(student, scores):
       print(f"Student Name: {student}")
       for score in scores:
          print(score)

listt = [100, 95, 88, 92, 99]
test_list("Jonathan", listt)
```

Comment: Это просто **синтаксический сахар**. Без них можно и обойтись.

Comment: Вот вам пример: Есть функция print. Она может принимать 0 или большее количество параметров (через `*args`). Если бы возможности такой передачи не было, пришлось бы или делать чтобы первым аргументом всегда был список (с 0 или больше элементов), или всегда выводить только один объект за раз. Можно, конечно, было бы проверять, если первый аргумент "атомарный", то выводить его, а если последовательность, то выводить каждый элемент последовательности отдельно, но тогда для вывода списка как списка пришлось бы удваивать квадратные скобки.